# Socks proxy in android

Tags: android

How to Connect SOCKS Proxy connection in android emulator, I am able to connect successfully SOCKS Proxy Server on system browser but it not work in emulator, when using System network setting. I have tried

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", port);
```

and also

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Proxy httpProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);urlConn = url.openConnection(httpProxy);
```

but Falied. I want to connect and consume SOCKS Proxy connection & Web Service in my App on Device.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Android 4.3 on rooted Nexus 4 with [SSHTunnel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sshtunnel&hl=en) running:

```
    SocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1984);  
    SocketAddress hostAddr = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
    java.net.Proxy proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr);
    socket = new Socket(proxy);
    socket.connect(hostAddr);
```

Note: I also installed [iptables beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mgranja.iptables&hl=en) but I'm not sure if it's required.

For this to work with an emulator change the IP to 10.0.2.2 which is Android's alias for your host machine.  You will have to run a local SOCKS proxy on your machine of course.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Android doesn't support SOCKS proxy out of the box, but you can try installing [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/), which can act as a HTTP proxy, and it can use a SOCKS upstream proxy. (I used it to hook up the Android emulator to [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/).) You can then [set up a HTTP proxy using the UI](https://techblog.vsza.hu/images/android-proxy-6pack.png) (so it can be even used on a real phone, not just the emulator). For more information, see [my blogpost about Android and TOR](https://techblog.vsza.hu/posts/Using_TOR_to_evade_Play_Store_geoban.html).

Comment: thanks, I try this, but got an java.net.ConnectException: - Connection refused